# get all elements with specific Classname in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-manipulation

I want to get all elements with the classname `selected` from this component

```
function ChooseElements() {
 
  const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) =>
  
    <ListItem key={object.id.toString()} value={object.Element} />
  );
  return (
    <div>   <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>

    <button onClick={ console.log("get all list items")}>get Elements</button>
    </div>
 
  );
}
```

in plain js i could use `document.getElementsByClassName('selected')` to get all elements

I have read somewhere that [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) should be used
to access the elements in the virtual dom, is this correct and how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably see it from a different perspective. You can lift your state one level up to your `<ChooseElements />` component.

This is the practice encouraged by react for similar problems. [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```
function ChooseElements() {
   const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

   const handleItemSelect = item => {
      setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, item]);
   }

   const handleItemUnselect = item => {
      setSelectedItems(selectedItems.filter(i => i !== item));
   }

   const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) =>
     <ListItem
        key={object.id.toString()}
        value={object.Element}
        onSelect={() => handleItemSelect(object)}
        onUnselect={() => handleItemUnselect(object)}
        />
   );

   return (
      <div>
         <ul>
           {listItems}
         </ul>
         <button onClick={() => console.log(selectedItems)}>get Elements</button>
      </div>
   );
}
```

However, if **ONLY AND ONLY** lifting state up is not possible to you, you can use ref like this:

```
function ChooseElements() {
   const myRef = useRef();

   const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) =>
     <ListItem
        key={object.id.toString()}
        value={object.Element}
        />
   );

   return (
      <div>
         <ul ref={myRef}>
           {listItems}
         </ul>
         <button onClick={() => {
            console.log(ref.current.querySelector('.selected'));
         }}>
            get Elements
         </button>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use document.querySelectorAll('.list-item') but you need to assign a classname first. example my class is `list-item` so you can get the DOM elements.